model.save('Siamese.keras') UnicodeEncodeError
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 8759: character maps to 
[enter image description
def Siamese(text_vectorizer, vocab_size=36224, d_feature=128):

    branch = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name='sequential') 

    branch.add(text_vectorizer)

    branch.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=d_feature, name='embedding'))
    
    
    branch.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=d_feature, return_sequences=True, name='GRU'))

    branch.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name='mean'))

    branch.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1), name='out'))
    
    
    
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name='input_1')
    input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name='input_2')
    
    
    branch1 = branch(input1)
    branch2 = branch(input2)
    
    
    conc = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1, name='conc_1_2')([branch1, branch2]) 
        
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=conc, name="SiameseModel")

here](https://i.sstatic.net/foLGAt6t.png)
I tried to save the model after training and i got that error.
